# Return value for minimum in group of columns

Tags: r

I have a group of columns, and I need a new column `min123` with the minimum value of these columns `123a_1` through `123a_5`.

```
dff <- structure(list(`MCI ID` = c("070405344", "230349820", "260386435","370390587", "380406805", "391169282", "440377986", "750391394","890373764", "910367024"), 
                      `123a_1` = structure(c(16672, 16372,16730, 16688, 16700, 16783, 16709, 17033, 16786, 16675), class = "Date"),
                      `123a_2` = structure(c(17029, 16422, 17088, 17036, 17057,17140, 17072, 17043, 17141, 17038), class = "Date"), 
                      `123a_3` = structure(c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
                      `123a_4` = structure(c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
                      `123a_5` = structure(c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), 
         .Names = c("MCI ID","123a_1", "123a_2", "123a_3", "123a_4", "123a_5"), row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)    
dff %>% 
    mutate(min123 = pmin(`123a_1`, `123a_2`, `123a_3`, `123a_4`, `123a_5`, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, second to that, is there a way to return the next to minimum value?

Answer (score 3):

A base R approach using `do.call` and `pmin`:

```
dff$min123 <- do.call(pmin, c(dff[-1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

A similar appraoch in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    
dff %>% 
  mutate(min123 = do.call(pmin, c(select(., -1), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Or `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dff)[, min123 := do.call(pmin, c(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = -1]
```

Comment: hah...I was just searching to see how to pass `na.rm` in `do.call` :)

Answer (score 0):

That's what the function `pmin`is for:

```
> str(dff)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ MCI ID: chr  "070405344" "230349820" "260386435" "370390587" ...
 $ 123a_1: Date, format: "2015-08-25" "2014-10-29" "2015-10-22" ...
 $ 123a_2: Date, format: "2016-08-16" "2014-12-18" "2016-10-14" ...
 $ 123a_3: Date, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ 123a_4: Date, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ 123a_5: Date, format: NA NA NA ...
> dff$groupmin <- pmin(dff[[2]],dff[[3]],dff[[4]], dff[[5]], dff[[6]], na.rm=TRUE)
> head(dff)
     MCI ID     123a_1     123a_2 123a_3 123a_4 123a_5   groupmin
1 070405344 2015-08-25 2016-08-16   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2015-08-25
2 230349820 2014-10-29 2014-12-18   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2014-10-29
3 260386435 2015-10-22 2016-10-14   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2015-10-22
4 370390587 2015-09-10 2016-08-23   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2015-09-10
5 380406805 2015-09-22 2016-09-13   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2015-09-22
6 391169282 2015-12-14 2016-12-05   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 2015-12-14
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as the `dplyr` solution

Comment: @Sotos For someone who is struggling with such an easy question, I gave an easy answer. Additional complexity introduced by using a non-standard library and non-standard syntax through pipes appears disadvantageous enough to justify another answer. It does not matter, as Jaap has the best answer so far: Standard R and concise! (has my upvote)

Comment: ok. If you think it has value then by all means.

Comment: @Sotos Yes I think it has value to teach people how to do things in standard R. My post has no more value after the post of Jaap nor after the "already has an answer"-link.

Comment: Ok. No problem. It's up to you. I was just clarifying